# convert a column of text into a paragraph

Tags: pandas

```
df_lyrics['Lyrics']

0       \n\n--Male--\nAaaaa Aaaaa\n--Female--\nAaaaaa\...
1       \n\n--Male1--\nAnkhiyon Hi Ankhiyon Mein\nRati...
2       \n\n--Male1--\nAray Peeli Chotiyaan,\nHawaeyn ...
3       \n\nPyar Itna Na Kar\nYeh Dil Jaata Hai Bhar\n...
4       Zaraa Maara Maara Sa\nJaane Kyun Dil Ye Ban Ba...
                          ...                        
1286     \n\nKaara fankaara kab aaye re\nKaara fankaar...
1287     \n\nZameen-o-aasmaan ne kya baat ki hai\nGira...
1288     \n\nMaula Wa Sallim wassalim da-iman abadan\n...
1289     \n\nBhavara\nRe ga re ga re ga re ga pa ma ga...
1290     \n\nArre udi udi udi... udi jaye..\n\nUdi udi...
Name: Lyrics, Length: 1291, dtype: object
```

I want to convert all these into a single paragraph....
Please help me.

Comment: this has nothing to do with NLP, deep learning or machine learning, kindly do not spam tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the strings using pd.Series sum:

```
print(df_lyrics['Lyrics'].sum())
```